# How do I evalulate a Func / Delegate / Expression passed as parameter to method?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates, func

I want to write an extension method that will run a method of some object, and return the exception that occurred during execution (if any).

In other words, make this dynamic for myObject.Foo() to be anyObject.AnyMethod(...).

```
Exception incurredException = null;
try 
{
    myObject.Foo();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    incurredException = e;
}

return incurredException;
```

To this:

```
Exception e = IncurredException( () => myObject.Foo() );
```

I have no idea if a Func, Expression, Delegate, etc. is appropriate here. Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: What you're doing there would be easiest as an `Action`. What do you want to do in the case that the method has a return type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about return types, you need something like this:

```
public static Exception IncurredException(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e;
    }

    return null;
}
```

You can then invoke it as you wanted with:

```
Exception e = IncurredException( () => myObject.Foo() );
```

Or a bit tidier, using `var` and method group syntax:

```
var e = IncurredException(myObject.Foo);
```

Comment: it's probably better to inline `incurredException` variable, just creates a confusion there. Body of `catch` would be `return e`, or better - rename `e` variable. Also, give some description about [swallowing **all**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding) occurred exceptions as bad design decision.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: Agree with you on inlining - updated. Not too sure about the swallowing part though? I can't see any evidence that the OP is intending to swallow any exceptions.

Comment: returning an exception and throwing it is two different cases.  Previously, return value indicated a possible error in C or C++. I'm far from being an expert in that area, but as far as I know that's the reason why exceptions where introduced in the first place.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: Thanks for the clarification. I see what you mean. I was kind of assuming the OP was planning to inspect the Exception, then rethrow as required. Maybe this point is best left in the comment, as it's design advice which is peripheral to the question itself. But feel free to edit my answer if you think otherwise.

Comment: not going to edit it, just wanted some comments or warnings about this approach.

Comment: @Baldrick yep the Action is what I was looking for. And specifically, I've made the method generic for any exception type, i.e. https://dotnetfiddle.net/5FhJM2